# Как сделать фон скошенный сбоку?

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка, веб-дизайн

Возможно ли в CSS сделать так, чтобы при ховере на пункты меню фон был не прямоугольный, а скошенный справа?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, например :before :after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Transform** - Трансформирует элемент, в частности, позволяет его масштабировать, вращать, сдвигать, наклонять, а также комбинировать виды трансформаций.

**SkewX** - Наклоняет элемент на заданный угол по вертикали.

**:Before** - Псевдоэлемент применяется для отображения желаемого контента до содержимого элемента, к которому он добавляется. Работает совместно со свойством `content`.

```css
a { 
    color: black;
    padding: 3px;
    position:relative;
}
ul{
    list-style:none;
}
li {
    padding: 5px; 
}
a:hover{ 
    background: #075d9f;
    color:white;
}
a:hover:before {
    top: 0;
    right: -8px;
    padding: 0.1px;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-11deg);
        -ms-transform: skewX(-11deg);
            transform: skewX(-11deg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #075d9f;
    z-index: -1;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head></head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно `clip-path` использовать как вариант

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: skyblue;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
}

li{
 width: 200px;
 position: relative;
 clip-path: polygon(0 1%, 100% 0, 90% 100%, 0% 100%);
 cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover{
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Первый</li>
  <li>Второй</li>
  <li>Третий</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Интересный вариант, но кроссбраузерность так себе.

Comment: Я сказал же, как вариант. А так префиксы рулят ) https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Comment: IE/Edge они не помогут...

Answer (score 3):

через `:after` делает треугольник. Угол треугольника регулируется за счет `border-top` и `border-right`. И подгоняется параметр `right`

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #002b55;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;  
}

.test:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  
}

.test span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;  
}

.test:hover {
  width: 100px;
  background: #224d77;
}

.test:hover:after { 
   border-top: 50px solid #224d77;
   
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"><span>Test1</span></div>
<div class="test"><span>Test2</span></div>
<div class="test"><span>Test3</span></div>
<div class="test"><span>Test4</span></div>
```

Еще примеры фигур https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Ты первый, но у меня немного по-другому))

Comment: @Qwertiy я чет только прочитал, что скос надо при ховере оказвца)

Comment: Да без разницы же. У меня даже margin есть, чтоб ничего не поллзало :)

Answer (score 2):

```css
h1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: silver;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  padding: 0 .25em;
  margin-right: .625em;
}

h1:hover span::after { /* или span:hover::after по необходимости */
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1.25em .625em 0 0;
  border-color: silver transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Заголовок</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Братцы, у вас слишком много кода.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 24px 8px 24px;
  color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(darkblue, darkblue);
}

span:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(110deg, darkblue 86%, transparent 86%);
}
```

```html
<span>тест</span>
```

Comment: зато у нас треугольники  с чёткой гипотенузой , а не понадкусанной :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а вы выкиньте свой хром в топку, он нормально градиенты не умеет рендерить. )))

Comment: Проблема в том, что такое плохое отображение будет в хроме,опере,яндекс браузере,IE,Edge - а это почти 80% всего интернета.(в safari и Android Browser я не смотрел). FF - используют ~ 7% (хотя там слегка тоже подхрамывает). Предлагаете 80%  пользователям сменить браузер? ну-ну)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я там смайлы поставил, это было для вас... а в принципе я бы предложил разработчикам webkit обратить внимание на проблему.